# user number shows instead of user name in posts

Tags: support

When I post to other stack exchange forums, the post shows my user name.  In Unix & Linux, it shows my user number.  What am I doing wrong?

See my comment to the top answer in
[How to log whatever I enter in terminal to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25001/how-to-redirect-whatever-i-enter-in-terminal-to-file?newsletter=1&nlcode=17737|321c)

Answer (score 2):

It actually is showing your display name -- here your display name is "user23861". You can edit [your profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10292/user23861) to change it -- the link is at the top-right of your profile page:

[Screenshot of the edit link http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-profile-edit.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-profile-edit.png)

You can also go to the "accounts" tab on your profile on another site (e.g., [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/37007/joe?tab=accounts)), and click the "Copy profile to all Stack Exchange accounts" button at the bottom:

[Screenshot of the button http://so.mrozekma.com/su-copy-profile.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/su-copy-profile.png)

When it copies your SU profile here it will also change your display name